# How is the path-integral over a spatially finite region calculated?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, approximations, discrete, thermal-field-theory

The partition function for a system in the path-integral formalism is given by

\begin{equation}
      \mathcal{Z}=\int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\psi^{\dagger}{e^{\int_0^{\beta}d\tau\int_Vd^3x\mathcal{L}}}
\end{equation}

where $\tau=-it$. For simplicity let $\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi$.

Most treatments of QFT take $V$ to be infinite and there seems to be a paucity of resources that systematically address finite systems. However there are finite systems which we would like to consider (for instance, a finite region of a star that is in local thermal equilibrium).

**Questions**: (1) If we want to describe a finitely extended system, do we simply take $V$ in the expression above to be finite? (2) When computing $\mathcal{Z}$ using a functional determinant, the eigenfunctions of $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)$ are taken to be anti-periodic in the temporal direction, which results in them having discrete temporal spectra. In the spatially finite case, do we also have to impose periodic boundary conditions in the spatial directions?

**Motivation**: Often in the literature an explicitly finite region is considered with $V=L_xL_yL_z$. However, when the thermodynamic potential is computed using a functional trace the following is reported as the result

\begin{equation}
        \nonumber{\Omega=\frac{\Phi}{V}=-\frac{1}{\beta}\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty }\displaystyle\int\frac{d^3k}{\left(2\pi\right)^3}\ln\left[\det\left(\gamma^0\frac{(2{n}+1)\pi}{\beta}+\gamma^ik_i+m\right)\right].}
    \end{equation}

The eigenfuctions of $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)$ thus appear to have temporally discrete spectra, but spatially continuous spectra, which suggests that the spatial boundaries are infinite. This is contrary to the finite volume assumption.

Comment: Which literature? Which page? They are presumably implicitly approximating integrals with sums, and vice-versa.

Comment: For instance here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3521. In the line right below equation (58), we can see that the integration region is taken to be finite, but in (A18) we can see that the thermodynamic potential has a discrete sum over Matsubara frequencies and a continuous integral over $p_3$.

Comment: Field theory in a finite volume is treated in some textbooks, e.g. in a Chapter in Zinn-Justin's QFT textbook. More details can be found in the literature, which I can provide if you specify what details you are interested in. If your spatial region has periodic BCs, you should choose the appropriate (periodic or antiperiodic) boundary conditions for your fields which are relevant to the physical problem you are considering. Your expression for the thermodynamic potential is the $V \rightarrow \infty$ limit.